# Selecting a node in the nested set model through a not-unique name

Tags: mysql, select, nested, set

I am trying to manage the retrieval of a node in a [nested set model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) table, not through the unique ID, but **through the name** (a string), and other nodes within the tree under different parents may be called the same way.

As far as now I used an unique ID to get nodes inside the nested sets:

```
SELECT
     node.name, node.lft, node.rgt
FROM tbl AS parent, tbl AS node
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
AND node.id = '{$node_id}'
GROUP BY node.id
```

Trying to extend this method to a more general way to retrieve the node through its name, I came up with a query containing as much HAVING clauses as the depth of the node to retrieve, checking for the node name and its depth:

```
SELECT
     node.name, node.lft, node.rgt, COUNT(node.id) AS depth
FROM tbl AS parent, tbl AS node
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.id
HAVING
     (node.name = 'myParentName' AND depth = 1)
     OR
     (node.name = 'myParent2Name' AND depth = 2)
     OR
     ...
 # and so on
```

But it is not perfect: having two nodes with the same name and the same depth, but within different parents, both are retrieved, no matter the hierarchy they belong to.

Example:

```
ARTICLES
   |
   +--PHP
   |   +--the-origins
   |   +--syntax
   +--JS
       +--history
       +--syntax
```

In this case, the query above would return either ARTICLES/PHP/syntax or ARTICLES/JS/syntax: a "syntax" node with depth 3, infact, is either under the PHP node or under the JS node.
Is there an effective path to walk, to solve this problem?

Comment: So, you're inputting for instance 'PHP' & 'syntax' and their respective depths, and you want their trail to the top? Or what is the exact input & output you want if that isn't the case?

Comment: Yes Wrikken, I am trying to do exactly that. I would take the depth from the given path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to access the node with the pathname `ARTICLES/PHP/syntax`? If so what you'd need to do would be a self-join for each parent level:

```
SELECT n0.*
FROM tbl AS n0
JOIN tbl AS n1 ON n0.lft BETWEEN n1.lft+1 AND n1.rgt
JOIN tbl AS n2 ON n1.lft BETWEEN n2.lft+1 AND n2.rgt
WHERE n0.name='syntax' AND n1.name='PHP' AND n2.name='ARTICLES'
```

ETA re comments: doing direct-child matches in nested set isn't much fun. You'd have to try to select an intermediate parent row between each joined row. This is the row you don't want to exist, so you then invert that condition with a null left join. eg.:

```
SELECT n0.*
FROM tbl AS n0
JOIN tbl AS n1 ON n0.lft BETWEEN n1.lft+1 AND n1.rgt
JOIN tbl AS n2 ON n1.lft BETWEEN n2.lft+1 AND n2.rgt
LEFT JOIN tbl AS nn1 ON nn1.lft BETWEEN n1.lft+1 AND n0.lft-1
LEFT JOIN tbl AS nn2 ON nn2.lft BETWEEN n2.lft+1 AND n1.lft-1
WHERE nn1.lft IS NULL AND nn2.lft IS NULL
AND n0.name='syntax' AND n1.name='PHP' AND n2.name='ARTICLES'
```

Comment: Thanks bobince: this method (progressive JOINs for each level) is the same used in the adjacendy model, so the nested set model also shows some limit in the retrieval task, is it right?

Comment: Yeah, nested set doesn't really get you anything here. Nested set gives you the ability to select a number of rows that satisfy some hierarchical relationship; here, you only want to select one row, so there's no advantage. An operation that nested set would be ideal for—having done the query above to get the target node's `lft`—would be to get all the ancestors of that node, which would be `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (node's lft value) BETWEEN lft AND rgt`.

Comment: Probably I explained poorly my task, but I need a node and its whole hierarchy, too. Of course I am using the nested set to avail myself of the specific advantages this technique brings: through it I wrote proper hierarchical methods for each task such as getParents(), getChildren(), getSiblings() and so on. Doing it by a given ID it is not a problem, since it is a unique identifier, but I would have liked to extend the retrieval task to the name. Getting the parents (the whole hierarchy of the requested element) is exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: WARNING: this query can produce invalid results because it is unable to distinguish between `ARTICLES/PHP/syntax` and `ARTICLES/PHP/legacy/sytnax`, since both paths satisfy the query.

Comment: Madbreaks: +1 Indeed, for an arbitrary-depth tree it would matter, and you'd have to ensure there were no in-between levels by doing a self-null-join between each level. Plenty tedious! Nested set's not good for this kind of query.

Comment: If you have time and could update your answer to show an example of what you mean by "self-null join between each level", I would sure appreciate it.  I've been grappling with this for a while!

Comment: @Madbreaks: Added, though I wouldn't necessarily recommend it unless you're desperate and this is a non-common query. Reaching the boundaries of what it is sensible to do with nested set!

Comment: This query is not working properly, even the edited version.If you have a tree of depth 3, with 5 nodes, one root, two going all the way left and two going all the way right, and both of the leaves are named the same thing, the query fails because of the null checking when you check for the bottom right leave (the bottom left one is in the left join result, hence no nulls)